# Python pandas json: output filenames if multiple json value completely matches what i set

Tags: python, json, pandas

### What I am trying to do

1. find all the files with the value corresponding  to a certain word
2. if true retrieve the filenames
3. continue searching through 5000.json files

> ex: pass through all the attributes:  if ( trait_type is "background"
> and the value matches "none") & (trait_type is skin and the value
> matches "Nothing") & .....

### Desired Outcome

```
    name: #2
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "none "
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Skin",
      "value": "Nothing"
    },
    .

   name: #5
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "pink "
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Skin",
      "value": "Nothing"
    },
    .
   name: #8
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "none"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Skin",
      "value": "Nothing"
    },
    .
```

> Output: #2 #8

## What I have

5000 .json files (the format is shown below) the only difference is the thing in the value

```
   {
  "name": "#1",
  "description": " ",

  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "pink "
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Mouth",
      "value": "NoMouth"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Clothing",
      "value": "white shirt "
    }
  ],
  "custom_fields": {
  }
}
```

### The Code I have

```
import json
# load data using Python JSON module
with open('build/json/_metadata.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    
# Flatten data
df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(
    data, 
    meta=['name'],
    record_path =['attributes'])

df_nested_list
```

Comment: My approach would be, - to loop through .jason files in the folder. During the loop, flatten and append one by one into to Dictionary with Pandas Dataframes while at the same time, adding new Column with a file name to each df, - later do all your fun tasks

Comment: @NoobVB Alright. I understand all the stuff before pandas dataframes but I have no idea how to add new column with a file name to each df. Is it something like DataFrame.insert()? Thanks

Comment: the question is good, but it **needs to be reduced** to the problem that you have identified so that others can answer it directly:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @D.L I made some changes now. If you have any possible solutions please let me know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as per my comment, a simplistic approach would be as below:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# creating list of json files with full paths
paths = Path(r'C:\PycharmProjects\Test\json_folder').glob("*.json")

df_list = [] # empty list to store dataframes during the loop
for p in paths:
    data = json.load(open(p))
    df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(
        data,
        meta=['name','description','custom_fields'],
        record_path=['attributes'])
    df_nested_list['file_name'] = p.name  # creating column to store file name: p.name
    df_list.append(df_nested_list) # dataframe to the list


df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True) # creating One Large Dataframe from all stored in the list
print(df.columns)
Index(['trait_type', 'value', 'name', 'description', 'custom_fields',
       'file_name'],
      dtype='object')

print(df)
```

out:

```
      trait_type         value name description custom_fields        file_name
0     Background         pink    #1                        {}  _metadata1.json
1           Skin    Lightbrown   #1                        {}  _metadata1.json
2       bookmark       normal    #1                        {}  _metadata1.json
3    accessories         None    #1                        {}  _metadata1.json
4         People           no    #1                        {}  _metadata1.json
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried it and I got either one of these two errors:
1)  "Index" is not defined
2) ValueError -->df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)  (if I comment out index)

I'll do some more tests and see if it can be fixed.

Comment: obviously, `df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)` will through an error, if  `df_list = []` was not updated with the list of dataframes.

Comment: as per `"Index" is not defined` - not sure which row caused it, cannot comment